# build.gradle error , Failed to resolve: common

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After I syn project with gradle files, I get this following error. `Open File` redirects me to build.gradle in app module.

```
 Failed to resolve: common
    Open File

Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
def rootConfiguration = {}
apply from: project(':app').file('config.gradle'), to: rootConfiguration

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4"
    }
}

//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion rootConfiguration.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ai.susi"
        minSdkVersion rootConfiguration.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootConfiguration.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.7"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        // for unit test
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"

    //piechart
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:${rootConfiguration.mpAndroidChartVersion}"

    //Leak Canary
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${rootConfiguration.leakCanaryVersion}"
    releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${rootConfiguration.leakCanaryVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${rootConfiguration.leakCanaryVersion}"

    //butterknife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${rootConfiguration.butterKnifeVersion}"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${rootConfiguration.butterKnifeVersion}"

    //For Picasso
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:${rootConfiguration.picassoVersion}"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${rootConfiguration.retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${rootConfiguration.retrofitVersion}"
    debugImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${rootConfiguration.okHttpVersion}"

    //For Link Previews
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:${rootConfiguration.jsoupVersion}" // required
    implementation "com.leocardz:link-preview:${rootConfiguration.linkPreviewVersion}"

    //preference UI
    implementation "com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:${rootConfiguration.preferenceVersion}"

    //unit test
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootConfiguration.supportLibraryVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:runner:${rootConfiguration.testVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test:rules:${rootConfiguration.testVersion}"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${rootConfiguration.espressoVersion}"

    //realm adapter
    implementation "io.realm:android-adapters:${rootConfiguration.realmVersion}"

    //waiting dots
    implementation "com.github.tajchert:WaitingDots:${rootConfiguration.waitingDotsVersion}"
    implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${rootConfiguration.crashlyticsVersion}") {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${rootConfiguration.kotlinVersion}"
}
```

app.gradle (project module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.41"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?
I have a common.jar file, where should I place it?

Comment: try by mooving mavenCentral before jcenter

Comment: try also by mooving maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }  to the top of allprojects{repositories{....

Comment: @E.Abdel still getting the same error, for the first one, i'll try the second one.

Comment: wow! it worked ! Thanks, you can write it as an answer, and would like to know how does order matter

Comment: It seems that android.arch.core:common-1.1.0 has been deleted from jcenter, already answred here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839322/errorfailed-to-resolve-android-arch-corecommon1-1-0

Comment: Worked for me by adding `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}`, I didn't have it or need it before now

Comment: @E.Abdel Thank you so much! That worked completely