# React Native - Run Android - Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

When run react-native run-android, I got this error :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-device-info'.
      > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563942/1713103) solution and works for me: 
add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in line 18 in file `android/build.gradle`

[image]

Comment: For me, this manages to compile the project, but on Android the app crashes on opening. Is your app working normally?

Comment: Yes, works perfect

Comment: Ah, it was just because adding this repository automatically updated the version of  play-services-base and play-services-maps. Needed to change it on build.gradle

Comment: @MaurícioAraldi How did you solved the  crashes  of the app after added maven url?

Comment: It would be interesting to know why this error is due

Comment: We have been having the same problem today and it seems like the bintray mirror where common.jar is hosted is out of sync or something - some requests work, most don't.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `jcenter()` and `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` make sure that `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` is written first (upper in code).

`android.arch.core:common:1.0.0` exists in `jcenter()`, but doesn't have `.jar` file there and thats why build fails. Using Google Maven first fixes this problem, because .jar exist there.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // <--- This needs to be before jcenter().
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it as your code. But still it is not working

Comment: This is correct. Ordering `maven` before `jcenter` means it will attempt to find the library dependency on `maven` first and only if it's not available on `maven` will it try `jcenter`.

Comment: This is exactly what's breaking everything. Thanks!

Comment: @Eddwhis I am also facing the same problem after adding react native fbsdk, In my `android/build.gradle` i do not see allprojects so shall i be adding that one or where shall i add that line?

Comment: @Mafijul - have you tried project clean? Or Android Studio "Invalidate cache and restart" ?

Comment: @user7747472 - you can try to add this block to build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a network issue with my Wifi (proxy...). Try to switch network with mobile data for example.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my root projects build gradle version and all the support libraries to latest version and its working now, you can check it go through, **build.gradle(root project) -> buildscript -> dependencies-> classpath->**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.your_latest_version'
```

also make sure your **compileSdkVersion** and **buildToolsVersion** are latest

and once check version of **distributionUrl** also from **gradle-wrapper.properties** file