# Failed to build plugin nativescript-google-maps-sdk

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

```
Unable to apply changes on device: xyz. Error is: Failed to build plugin nativescript-google-maps-sdk :
Error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1 Error output:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Tried below solutions to resolve this, but no luck

1. added maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } in `build.gradle` file
2. add/remove `nativescript-google-maps-sdk` plugin

Comment: Please post your build.gradle

Comment: Please check answer in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50761629/2595870

Answer (score 0):

I think that I arrive a little bit late, but I faced a really similar issue related with nativescript-google-maps-sdk and Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

I was having a similar output, but couldn't find any solution until I ran ns build android. With that command I got this output:

**General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 62 nativescript**

After searching a lot on internet I found that I have to downgrade my JDK version. I downgraded it from JDK 18 to JDK 8 and it solved my problem. Hope that this could be usefull to someone that presents a similar issue.