# react-native-fbsdk error Compilation failed Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)

Tags: java, android, reactjs, facebook, react-native

I am trying to add `Facebook social login` along `with wix react native navigation` . 
After adding facebook package to my application and configuring as per its documentation, the app stopped working. It started giving error saying

> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-fbsdk'.
>
>   > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).   Searched in the following locations:
>   >       https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

I tried to follow this thread [React Native - Run Android - Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568002/react-native-run-android-could-not-find-common-jar-android-arch-corecommon)
Tried adding the code below in the `android.builde` But that doesnt fix the issue.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // <--- This needs to be before jcenter().
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Here is my application files and configuration.**

- React native version 0.55
- React native fbsdk version 0.7.0
- Wix react native navigation version 1.1.458
- Platform Android

*My MainApplication.java*

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication  {

         private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

          protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
            return mCallbackManager;
          }

       @Override
       public boolean isDebug() {
           // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
           return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
       }

       protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
           return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
               // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
                 new VectorIconsPackage(),
                 new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
           );
       }

       @Override
       public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
           return getPackages();
       }

       @Override
       public String getJSMainModuleName() {
           return "index";
       }


}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;

import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
}
```

I tried to follow few other threads from [github/wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2262) , react native github and [stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568002/react-native-run-android-could-not-find-common-jar-android-arch-corecommon/50764968) , but no luck in fixing this issue