# Cordova build error on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, jcenter

I'm trying to build and execute my cordova project, but i'm facing the error:

```
BUILD FAILED                                                                                                           
Total time: 5.696 secs FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0). Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.1.0/common-1.1.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The point is that the same project was able to build/run last week, and today dont work anymore.
Anyone had this problem and found some solution?

Comment: Got the same issue. If I remove the fcm plugin (ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-fcm) and then try to build, it works. Is it the same case for you?

Comment: I actually got it working by this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839322/errorfailed-to-resolve-android-arch-corecommon1-1-0
I edited the files ..platforms\android\build.gradle and ..platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle and in them I replaced the
mavenCentral();
with
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
Then I remove fcm plugin and added again, and then i could build and run.
I can't tell though if this is a "good" solution.

Comment: I dont have this plugin intalled on my project, but maybe some of my plugins is causing that. 
i'll try this solution to see if will work to me too.

Comment: I think that solution is not bound to the fcm plugin in particular

Comment: Works, but now i'm having another error:
1-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem with barcode scanner plugin - i'm using ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

Open platforms/android/ then build.gradle

Add maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } before jcenter()

```
allprojects
 {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

google() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } are pointing to the same repo, google() is a Google's Maven repo shortcut. You can add google() instead of maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } IF you are using :

Gradle >= v.4.x+

It seems the order matters, 
**this works for me**