# Couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, jcenter

I'm new to Flutter and trying to run the example project when you create a new one. When trying to run it, I have this issue:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'PROJECTPATH/android/app/build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
  >   Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

I understand it's trying to get the file "lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar" from the jcenter repository but when following the link I get this:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}
```

So I added the Google repository in my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

...and I also succeed to get the file by following this link:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

...but I'm still getting the same error when trying to run my project, whether it is by using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), Android Studio or with the CLI.

How do I force Gradle to download the file from the link I've found?

Here's how my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar' }
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

....
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: It didn't, still getting the same error

Comment: For people coming here now, I think this has been fixed in master, so `flutter channel master` and `flutter upgrade` should sove it.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving:

```
maven {
    url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
}
```

in the top of:

```
jcenter()
```

in the file: `.flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you loads @Quentin. You saved me after 3 hours of trying various things. Gradle error seems like some dependency issue with a missing package.

Comment: Saved me. I was facing the same issue

Comment: Saved as well. Thanks a bunch

Comment: By the way, `.flutter` is `C:\flutter` on Windows (or the location of Flutter installation). It's not linked to a project.

Comment: did not see this working but definitely worked for me

Comment: I am struggling with this for a week and it didn't work for me, any ideas?
and I have to mention that I am using a VPN because I live in a country blocked by google

Comment: but if I click on the URL it downloads the file in the browser so actually I have the access, Can I use these files and where should I but them

Answer (score 44):

Modify `flutter.gradle` under ./flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle to upgrade the tools version to 3.2.1 and add `google()` to the first line:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUI67.png)

Comment: Upgrade your flutter，
This is my environmental information and I am working now.
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.104], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

Comment: Upgrade distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

Answer (score 21):

Regarding this error, I just changed this line in the `build.gradle` file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

And that solved my problem.

Comment: It is strange, but downgrading the gradle from 3.1.2 to 3.0.1(in my case) helped me.

Answer (score 16):

This is just a bug in the Gradle file located at `C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle` at line 25.

All you have to do is just edit this file by moving it to the  top:

```
maven {
    url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
}
```

Change from this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {`enter code here`
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is related to Flutter 0.9.4 at the moment. It will be fixed in the next release. In the meantime, you can update Flutter manually by running the commands described in "Flutter Upgrade". Basically they involve the following:

1. Change the Flutter GitHub channel to master by running on the command prompt:

   ```
   flutter channel master
   ```
2. Upgrade Flutter itself by running

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```

Once the upgrade is done, run the test drive application, and it should compile successfully.

Comment: You don't actually need to update the project dependencies repositories, so this answer is the one! :-D

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
Put
maven {
    url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
}
at the top of:
jcenter()
```

in the file: .flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle :
The file is in the Flutter SDK.

Comment: HII Aegon. I didn't find any flutter SDK. Where to find it. I have the same error?

Comment: You have to download the SDK first, here is a doc explains installation. https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install

Answer (score 3):

this fixed my issue,SO reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839322/errorfailed-to-resolve-android-arch-corecommon1-1-0/50885939#50885939):

In your root build.gradle make sure google() is before jcenter().

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

In most projects you will have to update this at 2 spots.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the previous answers resolve the problem. One comment to add is the location of the **flutte.gradle**.

You will find it in the directory that you installed Flutter in for the first time and not on the Flutter project.

Answer (score 2):

## Flutter Master Upgrade

I just had this problem. The fix for me however was a lot simpler. After switching branches to `dev` and upgrading, I switched back to `master` and it worked perfectly fine.

```
flutter checkout dev
flutter upgrade
```

Then switch back

```
flutter checkout master
flutter upgrade
flutter run
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try to upgrade Flutter using the following:

```
flutter upgrade
```

(This issue has been fixed in the latest update.)

Answer (score 1):

I also newbie in flutter and just installed it today. And I found the same problem as you, but after three hours googling I finally solved it.

The steps I have done are as follows:

1. Copy "flutter.gradle" file from "https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle" into "C:\flutter\packages\gradle"
2. Then modify the content, for this part:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
       }
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven {
                   url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
           }
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
       }
   }
   ```
3. In "c:\flutter\bin", run this command:

   ```
   flutter channel master
   ```

   Wait until finished, and then run this command:

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```
4. Wait until it finished, then re-run the project to debug,
5. and finally the application appeared on the emulator screen.

   [Picture finally running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wahAF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

For me, opening the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and editing the below line like this version solved it:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this error Flutter 1.0 had been released. The previous issues were fixed and still I was getting the same error.

The following steps fixed it for me :

1) Changing Gradle plugin version from 3.1.2 to 3.2.1 in `your_project/android/build.gradle` inside 'dependencies' section -

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
```

2) Changing Gradle wrapper version from 4.4 to 4.6 in `your_project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` like so

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Actually, changing Gradle plugin version from "3.2.1" to "3.1.2" worked for me! What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I have fix just by replacing these sentences:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'

        }
    }
}
```

instead of these:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

in build.gradle file and then replace `compile` with `implementation` in dependencies

Comment: Thank you . so much . .

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it with update version build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        ..............
}
```