# Unable to run flutter sample in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

i am new in flutter i just want to start it with android studio
but when i am just try to the simple app it shows me some error

can some one help me

```
Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\saswatsaubhagya\Desktop\flutter\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\saswatsaubhagya\Desktop\flutter\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:

   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
timeout waiting for the application to start
```

Comment: 1) What does `flutter doctor` say and 2) have you been able to build a helloworld type flutter app via the codelabs: https://flutter.io/codelabs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)