# When I am trying to setup my flutter environment in android studio it is giving me lots of error So What to do now?

Tags: flutter

These are the errors i am facing [It is showing module sdk is  not set please see the log [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzGTW.jpg)

Comment: Enter the error message into the Google search field ;p https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23404

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)